# Change App Icon at runtime from server

Tags: ios, iphone

I wanted to know if its possible to get the app icon from server anyway at runtime to change it dynamically other than the way introduced in iOS 10 to give it an alternate app icon.

Any insight into this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: all various app icons __must be__ embedded into the bundle, you can switch between those with no issue but you cannot download icon dynamically from external resources nor generate a new app icon in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get app icon from server and change it dynamically, as apple has introduced alternate app icon feature in  iOS 10.3. but you have to put app icon in App bundle and also defined icon in info.plist too.